# How can I implement java interface to java class

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I need help figuring out the following problem :
Create a class Statistics.java to implement the StatisticsI.java. Statistics.java contains ArrayList data to store to data objects of Double type, and properties (attributes): count, min, max, mean, std. The implementation has the following specifications.

```
addData(Double d) adds data d into the array list, and then update the values of count, min, max, mean, and std, using incremental algorithms, i.e. using exiting existing value to calculate new values, rather than calculating by traversal through the data array.
getCount() returns count.
getMin() returns min.
getMax() returns max.
getMean() returns mean.
getSTD() returns std.
stats() computes the count, min, max, mean, and stddev from the data array in one loop, and then sets the values of the properties.
```

I have the interface

```
public interface StatisticsI {
    void addData(double d);

    int getCount();

    double getMin();

    double getMax();

    double getMean();

    double getSTD();

    void stats();
}
```

Here is the code I have so far for the implementation part.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Statistics implements StatisticsI {
    private ArrayList<Double> data;
    private long count;
    private double min;
    private double max;
    private double mean;
    private double std;

    public Statistics() {
        data = new ArrayList<Double>();
        count = 0;
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
        mean = 0;
        std = 0;
    }

    public void addData(double d) {
        data.add(d);
        count += 1;
        data.set(data.indexOf(min), min);
        data.set(data.indexOf(max), max);
        data.set(data.indexOf(mean), mean);
        data.set(data.indexOf(std), std);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        count = data.size();
        return (int) count;
    }

    public double getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public double getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public double getMean() {
        int mean = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            double currentNum = data.get(i);
            mean += currentNum;
        }
        return mean / data.size();
    }

    public double getSTD() {
        {
            double avg = getMean();
            double t = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                double numbers = data.get(i);
                double value = Math.pow(numbers - avg, 2);
                t += value;
            }
            double std = (double) t / (double) (data.size());
            return Math.sqrt(std);
        }
    }

    public void stats() {
        count = data.size();
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with the addData and stats methods and I am not sure if I am doing this correctly and I am trying to figure out how to implement it.

My question is how to implement the interface with what is required in the methods.

Update: How do I call the methods from Statistics
Here is the code for the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Double> numList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        StatisticsI stats = new Statistics();
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            numList.add((double) r.nextInt(10000));
        } 
        double count = stats.getCount();
        double min = stats.getMin();
        double max = stats.getMax();
        double mean = stats.getMean();
        double std = stats.getSTD();
        
         System.out.println("The count for the list is:"+ count);
         System.out.println("The min for the list is:" + min);
            System.out.println("The max for the list is:" + max);
            System.out.println("The mean for the list is:" + mean);
            System.out.println("The standard deviation for the list is:" + std);
            
        
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't get any values for my output, I get :

```
The count for the list is:0.0
The min for the list is:Infinity
The max for the list is:-Infinity
The mean for the list is:0.0
The standard deviation for the list is:NaN
```

How do I get my output to work?

Comment: You seem to be doing it right. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do what is required for addData  and stats methods. How to update values and compute them.

Comment: You should read the specification carefully. Only methods stats() and addData() should change the state. The getters should only return the precalculated values. In addData() the specification says you should an incremental algortithm. So e.g. for max you should compare the new values with max and change max to the new value if the new value is greater. In stats() you have to calculate the values in a loop.

Comment: Regarding the update: you don't need `numList` in `main` method, you should have added the data to `stats`: `stats.addData(r.nextDouble() * 10_000)` and then called `stats.stats()` to update the statistics.

Answer (score 0):

in addData(..), use "min = Math.min(min, d)".  Math.max also exists, but std and mean are trickier.  It's probably easiest to calculate those in the getters by iterating the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can update `min`, `max`, `mean` values immediately in `addData`.

**Update** It is also possible to use [Welford's algorithm](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) to calculate running deviation.

```java
double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

double variance = 0.0;

public void addData(double d) {
    data.add(d);
    count++;
    if (d < min) {
        min = d;
    } else if (d > max) {
        max = d;
    }
    // fixed calculation of running mean and variance by Welford's algorithm
    double new_mean = mean + (d - mean) / count;    
    variance += count < 2 ? 0.0 : (d - mean) * (d - new_mean);
    mean = new_mean;
    std = count > 1 ? Math.sqrt(variance / (count - 1)) : 0;     
}
```

Or, you can reset all these values in `stats()` method using the `data` list.
There is a convenient way to calculate all stats at once via `DoubleSummaryStatistics` and Java 8 Stream API:

```java
public void stats() {
    DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = data.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(x -> x));
    count = stats.getCount(); // long value returned instead of `int data.size()`
    min = stats.getMin();
    max = stats.getMax();
    mean = stats.getAverage();
    std = this.getSTD();
}

public double getSTD() {
    double avg = getMean();
    double t = 0.0;
    for (double d : data) {
        t += Math.pow(avg - d, 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(t / getCount());
}
```

Loop-based "streamless" calculation of `stats` including ["naive" variance calculation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) for `std` could be as follows:

```java
public void stats() {
    count = data.size();
    min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    mean = 0.0;
    variance = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double sq = 0.0;
    int i = 0;
    for (double d : data) {
        min = Math.min(min, d);
        max = Math.max(min, d);
        i++;
        // calculate running mean as above to use in variance
        double new_mean = mean + (d - mean) / i;
        variance += i < 2 ? 0 : (d - mean) * (d - new_mean);
        mean = new_mean;
            
        sum += d;
        sq += d * d;
    }
    System.out.println("running mean=" + mean);

    std = count > 1 ? Math.sqrt((sq - mean * mean / count) / (count - 1)) : 0;

    mean = count == 0 ? 0 : sum / count;
}

// override STD getter to remove all calculations
public double getSTD() {
    return std;
}
```

Test

```java
Statistics stats = new Statistics();
stats.addData(17);
stats.addData(19);
stats.addData(24);

System.out.println("after addData()");      
System.out.println("mean=" + stats.getMean());
System.out.println("std=" + stats.getSTD());

System.out.println("after addData()");      
stats.stats();
System.out.println("mean=" + stats.getMean());
System.out.println("std=" + stats.getSTD());
```

**Output**

```
after addData()
mean=20.0
std=3.605551275463989

after stats()
running mean=20.0
mean=20.0
std=3.605551275463989
```

Comment: I followed this but now I am having a problem with my output for main class. I updated my question.

Comment: @newtoMobileDev You added the values NOT to the `Statistics` instance but to some outer `numList`